# Usar valor de variável para compor o comando de chamar funções

Tags: javascript

Quando começo a abstrair em várias funções meus sistemas, quase sempre me aparece essa dúvida. Estou com o valor "local" na variável sPrg, e preciso concatenar com "Ctrl.gravar" para chamar a função.

Como eu posso reduzir isso de forma a não precisar usar o `switch`?

```
ctrl.gravar = function (sPrg) {
   switch(sPrg){
      case "local":
         localCtrl.gravar();
         break;
      case "banco":
         bancoCtrl.gravar();
         break;
      case "cartao":
         cartaoCtrl.gravar();
         break;
      case "saldo":
         saldoCtrl.gravar();
         break;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Resposta rápida

Os tipos de ctrl (portanto, as opções do switch) poderiam ser atributos de um objeto:

```
// no plural
const ctrls = {
  local: localCtrl,
  banco: bancoCtrl,
  cartao: cartaoCtrl,
  saldo: saldoCtrl
};

ctrl.gravar = function(sPrg) {
    ctrls[sPrg].gravar();
}
```

## Bônus

Utilizando a sintaxe linda de arrow functions:

```
ctrl.gravar = sPrg => ctrls[sPrg].gravar();
```